# Game using file input/output, highscore storing and reading issue in file

Tags: c, file, file-io, io

This is a base bombing game using file input output. Highscore gets stored in binary file, but when the game is played again the previous highscore is shown as zero at the time of execution. Each time the new player becomes the highscorer and binary data in file gets changed according to his score and name.

I am also getting problem in displaying the name of the highscorer.
If someone gets the error of using fopen_s instead of fopen then go to your project properties and in preprocessor definitions add `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS;`.

```
/*

* BASE BOMBER: A Simple Computer Game

* Created by Muhammad Kaab and Muhammad irteza khan, 1/1/2016

*/

#include <stdio.h>             /* for printf() and file I/O functions */ 

#include <stdlib.h>            /* for rand() function */

#include <ctype.h>             /* for toupper() function */

#include<conio.h>              /* for getch() function */ 

#include<time.h>               /* for time(NULL) function */ 

#include <math.h>              /* for sqrt() function */ 

#include <string.h>            /* for strcmp() function */                                      




#define HIGHSCOREFILE "hiscore.txt"

#define CHEATCODE "Cheater"

#define GRIDSIZE_X 150

#define GRIDSIZE_Y 150

#define MAXBOMBS 100

#define TIMELIMIT 500

#define MAXBUFFLEN 50

#define MAXNAMELEN 50




/* Data structure for grid coordinates */


struct coordinates

{
int x;
int y;

};


/* Data structure for the player's name and score */


struct player

{
char name[MAXNAMELEN];
unsigned long score;

};


void get_coordinates(struct coordinates  *guess)

{
char buffer[MAXBUFFLEN];
enum { FALSE, TRUE } outofrange;

do {

    /* Ask the player for the bomb coordinates in the required format */

    printf("Enter bomb coordinates: ");
    fgets(buffer, MAXBUFFLEN, stdin);
    sscanf(buffer, "(%u,%u)", &guess->x, &guess->y);

    /* Check whether the player entered some valid coordinates */

    if (guess->x > GRIDSIZE_X)
    {
        outofrange = TRUE;
    }

    else if (guess->y > GRIDSIZE_Y)
    {
        outofrange = TRUE;
    }

    else
    {
        outofrange = FALSE;
    }

    /* If the entered values are invalid then tell the player to reenter 
them in the correct format */

    if (outofrange == TRUE)
    {
        printf("Those coordinates not valid.\n");
        printf("Please enter some valid coordinates like this: (%u,%u)\n", 
rand() % GRIDSIZE_X, rand() % GRIDSIZE_Y);
        printf("The top left corner of the grid is (0,0)\n\tand the bottom 
right corner is (%u,%u).\n", GRIDSIZE_X - 1, GRIDSIZE_Y - 1);
    }
} while (outofrange == TRUE);


}



int main()

{
FILE *scorefile;
char buffer[MAXBUFFLEN];
struct coordinates    target, guess;
struct  player        player, highscore;
double distance;
int bombs, starttime, timeleft, timelimit, i;
timelimit = 0;



printf("\n*********************************\n");
printf("***                          ***\n");
printf("***   Welcome to BASE BOMBER    ***\n");
printf("***                          ***\n");
printf("*********************************\n\n");


/* Choose the target base location */

srand(time(NULL));
target.x = rand() % GRIDSIZE_X;
target.y = rand() % GRIDSIZE_Y;
bombs = MAXBOMBS;

/* Ask the player for their name and store it in the player structure */

printf("Please tell me your name, Captain.\n");
printf("Your name: ");
fgets(player.name, MAXNAMELEN, stdin);

/* Remove the newline character stored by fgets by replacing it with a null 
*/
for (i = 0; player.name[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    if (player.name[i] == '\n')
    {
        player.name[i] = '\0';
    }
}

/* Convert the first character of the player's name into uppercase */

player.name[0] = toupper(player.name[0]);
printf("\nNice to meet you, Captain %s.\n", player.name);

/* set the player's score to zero */

player.score = 0;

/* If a previous high score was saved, retrieve and store it in the 
highscore structure */
highscore.score = 0;
scorefile = fopen(HIGHSCOREFILE, "r");

/* Only read the highscore if the highscore file could be opened */

if (scorefile != 0)
{
    if (fread(&highscore, sizeof(struct player), 1, scorefile) != 0)
    {
        fclose(scorefile);
    }
}

/* Display the game rules and objective */

printf("\nYour mission:\n");
printf(" You have %u seconds to locate and bomb the target base.\n", 
TIMELIMIT);
printf(" The target base is located on a %u x %u grid.\n", GRIDSIZE_X, 
GRIDSIZE_Y);
printf(" We do not know where exactly the target base is, but we can 
intercept their\n\tradio communications.\n");
printf(" Every time a bomb is dropped, they report the distance of bomb from 
their\n\tbase to their HQ by radio.\n");
printf(" We will intercept and tell you this information so that you can 
decide\n\twhere to drop the next bomb.\n");
printf(" Enter the (x,y) coordinates of the target like this: (%u,%u)\n", 
rand() % GRIDSIZE_X, rand() % GRIDSIZE_Y);
printf(" We only have %u bombs and each bomb is expensive, so try not to 
waste bombs.\n", bombs);
printf(" Good luck!\n\n");
printf("Press ENTER to start the mission. The timer will start 
immediately.\n");

fgets(buffer, MAXBUFFLEN, stdin);

/* Get the current time in seconds and calculate the game expiry time */

starttime = time(NULL);
timelimit = starttime + TIMELIMIT;

/* If the user entered the cheatcode, inform them of the target base 
coordinates */

if (strcmp(player.name, CHEATCODE) == 0)
{
    printf("Good news! Our spy just reported that the target base is at 
(%u,%u).\n\n", target.x, target.y);
}


/* This is the main game loop */

while (true)
{
    /* Calculate the time remaining and tell the player */

    timeleft = timelimit - time(NULL);
    printf("Countdown until mission ends: %u minutes", timeleft / 60);

    if ((timeleft % 60) != 0)
    {
        printf(", %u seconds.\n", (timeleft % 60));
    }
    else
        printf(" exactly.\n");

    /* Tell the player how many bombs are remaining */
    /* We display "There are n bombs left." if n > 1, otherwise we display 
"There is only 1 bomb left." */

    printf("There %s %u bomb%s left.\n", (bombs>1) ? "are" : "is", bombs, 
(bombs>1) ? "s" : "");

    /* Get the coordinates from the player */

    get_coordinates(&guess);

    /* Check that the time has not passed the expiry time */

    timeleft = timelimit - time(NULL);

    if (timeleft <= 0)
    {
        printf("\nSorry, Captain %s, you ran out of time!\n", player.name);
        printf("Mission failed.\n");
        break;
    }

    /* Calculate the Euclidean distance of the bomb from the target base 
using Pythagorus's theorem */

    distance = (((double)target.x - (double)guess.x)*((double)target.x - 
(double)guess.x)) + ((((double)target.y - (double)guess.y)*((double)target.y 
- (double)guess.y)));
    distance = sqrt(distance);

    /* Check whether the player hit the target */

    if (distance == 0)
    {
        printf("\nCongratulations, Captain %s! You successfully bombed the 
target base!\n", player.name);
        printf("Mission accomplished!\n");

        /* Calculate the player's final score */

        player.score = timeleft + 50 * bombs;
        break;
    }

    else
    {
        printf("The bomb was dropped at (%u,%u)\n", guess.x, guess.y);
        printf("The distance of the bomb from the target base was %lf\n\n", 
distance);
    }

    /* Decrement the number of bombs and end the game if there are no bombs 
left */

    bombs--;

    if (bombs == 0)
    {
        printf("Sorry, Captain %s, there are no more bombs left!\n", 
player.name);
        printf("Mission failed.\n");
        break;
    }
}

/* Display the player's score */

printf("\nYou scored %u points!\n", player.score);

/* If a highscore has been previously saved, then tell the player what it 
was */

if (highscore.name != 0)
{
    printf("The highest score earned was %u points by Major %s.\n", 
highscore.score, highscore.name);

}
/* If the player has beaten the highscore and did not cheat, then save the 
player's name and score in the highscore file */

if (((player.score > highscore.score) && strcmp(player.name, CHEATCODE)) != 
0)
{
    printf("You have beaten the highest score and earned a promotion!\n");
    printf("Well done, Major %s!\n", player.name);

    /* Try to open the highscore file for writing, overwriting it if it 
already exists */

    scorefile = fopen(HIGHSCOREFILE, "w");

    /* Only save the player's name and score if the highscore file could be 
opened */

    if (scorefile != NULL)
    {
        fwrite(&player, sizeof(char), MAXBUFFLEN, scorefile);
        fclose(scorefile);
    }
}
_getch();

return (0);

}
```

Comment: It is hard to understand your question. Please format it better and make full sentences.

Comment: when the game is played for the first time the score is stored as highscore in the file.
but when it is played again then even if i score less than the previous score it still says that you have broken the previous record.

Comment: basically i am facing problem in reading from and writing data to the file.
for example if i scored 500 it will get scored in the file. but when i play again that score of 500 is shown as 0 during execution.

Comment: See my answer, that should fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading and writing the data in different ways:

```
if (fread(&highscore, sizeof(struct player), 1, scorefile) != 0)
{
    fclose(scorefile);
}
```

Here, a `struct player` is read in (you also need to bring the `fclose()` outside this block).

```
scorefile = fopen(HIGHSCOREFILE, "w");

if (scorefile != NULL)
{
    fwrite(&player, sizeof(char), MAXBUFFLEN, scorefile);
    fclose(scorefile);
}
```

Here, `MAXBUFFLEN` == 50, which is also the length of the name, so there is no score stored. You have to write a `struct player` here also:

```
fwrite(&player, sizeof(struct player), 1, scorefile);
```

See:

```
#define MAXBUFFLEN 50
#define MAXNAMELEN 50

struct player
{
    char name[MAXNAMELEN];
    unsigned long score;
};
```

Comment: still  not getting the right highscore value

Comment: can you tell me how to read and write in text format instead of binary?

Comment: @IrtezaKhan - did you change `fwrite(&player, sizeof(char), MAXBUFFLEN, scorefile);` to write a struct player instead?

Comment: thanks alot i think your answer worked :)